# Perl 6 DBIish broken

Tags: mysql, raku

I've installed the DBIish on my macOS v10.13 (High Sierra):

```
zef install DBIish
```

And my test script is:

```
use v6;
use DBIish;

my $host='xxx.xx.xxx.xxx';
my $password='abc@123';


my $dbh = DBIish.connect('mysql', :host, :port(3306),
        :database<ald_xinen>, :user<aldwx>, :$password);

my $sth = $dbh.do(q:to/STATEMENT/);
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nom
    STATEMENT

$sth = $dbh.do(q:to/STATEMENT/);
    CREATE TABLE nom (
        name        varchar(4),
        description varchar(30),
        quantity    int,
        price       numeric(5,2)
    )
    STATEMENT

$sth.finish;
$dbh.dispose;
```

But when I run it, it got this:

```
This type cannot unbox to a native string: P6opaque, Bool
  in block  at /Users/ohmycloud/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/site/sources/F2D45FC1BC0A15B4C8511E3A864F1FC1C3F269BB (DBIish) line 41
  in any  at /Users/ohmycloud/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/site/precomp/D3F1031B6C577F31F20F165D75D09B8D4CFEDE2F.1507566035.94084/F2/F2D45FC1BC0A15B4C8511E3A864F1FC1C3F269BB line 1
  in method CALL-ME at /Users/ohmycloud/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/sources/24DD121B5B4774C04A7084827BFAD92199756E03 (NativeCall) line 550
  in method connect at /Users/ohmycloud/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/site/sources/9FB1D6F036EF609AD1246C9C77F064F5626EAED2 (DBDish::mysql) line 22
  in method connect at /Users/ohmycloud/.rakudobrew/moar-nom/install/share/perl6/site/sources/F2D45FC1BC0A15B4C8511E3A864F1FC1C3F269BB (DBIish) line 45
  in block <unit> at /Users/ohmycloud/Downloads/u/ald/Documents/scripts/dbiish.p6 line 8
```

My Rakudo version is:

```
This is Rakudo version 2017.09-361-g484f98725 built on MoarVM version 2017.09.1-575-gd4e230a6
implementing Perl 6.c.
```

So, how do I get this script to work?

Comment: em, I used rakudobrew to build my rakudo, I'll try [rakudo-star-2017.07](https://rakudo.perl6.org/downloads/star/rakudo-star-2017.07.dmg)

Comment: but still get the same error:
    This type cannot unbox to a native string: P6opaque, Bool
    . This is Rakudo version 2017.07 built on MoarVM version 2017.07
implementing Perl 6.c.

Comment: I suggest you post a bug report at [DBI's issue queue](https://github.com/perl6/DBIish/issues) (with just the Rakudo Star 2017.07 details).

Comment: yes, thank you. If solved, I will come back to edit this question again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the $ on the host parameter to connect.

Comment: Good find!  One wonders whether that should be coerced automatically or not.  Had it been coerced to "True", the problem would probably have become clear much earlier.  Or perhaps better: have a `Str:D` as a type restriction on `:$host`, and `Int:D` as type restriction on  `:$port` in `DBIish`.  That would also have shown the problem much earlier.

Comment: oh,yes, thanks. I forget the dollar `$` and `$sth.execute();` statement, but the error may mislead me

Comment: The error message was like that because the parameters passed to the MySQL connect were being passed straight through to the native method and the NativeCall implementation was attempting to unbox the value to the string it expected.

I have altered the connect() method for MySQL so that the parameters are explicitly stated and typed.